# Visual Studio 2017 like IDE for Ubuntu/Linux?

Tags: 18.04, c++, ide, cmake

I program A LOT and I want to switch to Ubuntu 18.04, the only thing stopping is that I don't have a good IDE. Currently I have a dualboot with Ubuntu 18.04 and Windows 10, on Ubuntu, I currently run CodeBlocks, it does its job, but it's far from Visual Studio...
I need A IDE with:

1. Runtime Code checking(where it puts a red line under it if it thinks it is incorrect, like VS)(MANDATORY).
2. A way to have multiple projects in the same window, so I can use CMake to generate a solution(whatever it's called for other IDE's) and have multiple projects in there, so I can easily see what code files belong to what project.
3. Preferably a UI as close to VS as possible.
4. A way to have CMake generate a project for it.(MANDATORY)
5. C++ support is MANDATORY!

What would match these requirments best? Especially 1, 4 and 5 is important.

Thanks!

Comment: [Try this IDE](https://www.jetbrains.com/) It's for all OS.

Comment: @VladSpirin It's not a full ide, CLion is just an editor, ubuntu already has an intergrated one. I need one that can compile the project too, and has the features mentioned above.

Comment: Use [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) by Microsoft, can compile for gcc-7, python, java, and many more...

Comment: @TimLeijten CLion is a full-featured IDE, not "just an editor". For me not only it serves as a great replacement for VS on mac/linux, but in many ways excels it.